# How to output to csv in respective columns

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I am reading csv files form multiple zip files to a dataframe and then using .to_csv to save the df with the below code.

```py
import glob
import zipfile
import pandas as pd
   
dfs = []
for zip_file in glob.glob(r"C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\Temp\*.zip"):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file)
    dfs += [pd.read_csv(zf.open(f), header=None, sep=";", encoding='latin1') for f in zf.namelist()]
    df = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
    
    df.to_csv("C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\Temp\data.csv")
```

However, I am getting a single column with `,` seperator
example:

```bash
    0
    
    0       Div,Date,HomeTeam,AwayTeam,FTHG,FTAG,FTR,HTHG,...
    
    1       SC3,05/08/00,Albion Rvs,East Fife,0,1,A,0,0,D,...
    
    ...
    
    215179                                          ,,,,,,,,,
```

There are `NaN` values as well in the `df`

Is there any way to save the df with proper structure and data in respective columns?

Comment: why did you specify a `;` separator when it appears to be `,` delimited?

Comment: If I change the `sep=";"` to `sep=","` I get this error: `pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 19 fields in line 353, saw 28`

Comment: It looks like the data entries in your csv files are not consistent and you skip the header despite the file having one. Try to load one csv file first and see if you can fix the issues before looping over all of them.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. the data runs from 1993 to yesterday so a few CSVs dont have the columns but the latest csv has all the required columns. How can I use the lastest CSV as a reference and then fill in the data as per those columns? my lastest csvs are stored in `"C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\Temp\data_19-20.zip"`

Comment: [Current Output](http://wikisend.com/download/653182/Current_output.csv) and  [Expected Output](http://wikisend.com/download/694092/Expected_output.csv)